# Relative filepath with HttpWebRequest object

Tags: c#, path, httpwebrequest

I am trying to create unittests that can be shared amongst my development team so I need to have all paths in the project be relative.

Where this is giving me trouble is with the HttpWebRequest class.
I want it to serve static testdata from a file in the local filesystem.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
file:///./TestData/test.html
```

But that just produces C:\TestData\test.html and a DirectoryNotFoundException.

The code for the HttpWebRequest looks like this:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
var response = request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
return responseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

How can I convince C# to resolve a relative path without breaking the Uri syntax?

greetings Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the file you are trying to server have a relative path compared to any of the assemblies in your project?  If so then you could build a non-relative URL based on the path of one of the assemblies and return that to the caller.

For Example:

```
var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(MyType).Assembly.Location);
var fullPath = Path.Combine(basePath, @"TestData\test.html");
return new Uri(fullPath);
```

Comment: Why would you use typeof(MyType).Assembly.Location instead of Environment.CurrentDirectory?

Comment: @Daniel, it's very easy for a program to alter Environment.CurrentDirectory and thus makes a solution depending on that fragile.  It's very difficult/impossible to change the path of an assembly.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need a webrequest if it's on the file system? you can just open it with File.ReadAllText(path)

Comment: The final production system would query data from a remote server.
During special tests I want to serve local files acting like a remote server.

Comment: yea but all this method is doing is returning the HTML as a string so for testing purposes File.ReadAllText should suffice IMO